# Plain Text in Vertical Alignment in HTML

Tags: html

How to set any plain text in Vertical Alignment in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS property `vertical-align` ist only either for vertical alignment in table cells or for vertical alignment of inline elements to each other.

There is no real vertical centering in CSS, but there way to "work around" it:

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

More alternatives: http://www.google.com/search?&q=css+vertical+centering

Answer (score -2):

```
<div style="vertical-align: top;">plain text</div>
```