# How to center contents or divs

Tags: css

I used 
    vertical-align: middle;
but it's not working
I dont wana use 
    margin-top:80px

see fiddle for more details http://jsfiddle.net/chanduzalte/2vwkA/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plain Text in Vertical Alignment in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929389/plain-text-in-vertical-alignment-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

I always refer to this great article on CSS-Tricks - http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 1):

Use `style=" display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"`

Check out this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/2vwkA/18/)

Answer (score 0):

If that is going to remain fixed (height of the box and only one line of text inside that box) then you can achieve that by adding line-height:

```
.center div{line-height:200px}
```